# Linq query to get parent id, grandparent id, etc right up to the root id

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, nhibernate

I have the following class

```
public class Category
{
public virtual int ID { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual int? ParentID { get; set; }  
public virtual IList<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I am mapping a database table with a self referencing foreign key relationship with fields id, name and parent id to this class using Nhibernate (though it could be the entity framework the orm doesn't really matter).

Given any category I need a method/query that gives me the category parentid, grandparentid etc.  I think one way of doing it is using a method that works recursively extracting successive parentids and stopping when it hits a null parentid.  The best I've come up with so far is to do something along the lines of

```
 newcategory = Load<Category>(category.parentId)
 add newcategoryid to list
 category = newcategory
 repeat until category.parentid is null
```

But I wondered if there could be performance problems with something like this as it could involve numerous trips to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework would probably have a hard time with this as you mentioned. You could load everything into memory for that table and then use LINQ to recurse up the hierarchy.

```
var categories = from c in category
                 select c;
//ToList executes the SQL statement once
var catList = categories.ToList()
//recurse over in-memory list
```

Or you could create a SQL stored procedure and just call it with EF.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea to me!  Would it improve performance if you cached the linq query.  Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: It depends on how much data you are dealing with and the fault tolerance - how often is the data updated? Can you cache for an hour and miss some updates or will you need to update the cache every minute?

Comment: At present it is a small amount of data - 20 records but will grow but will never be more than 500 records.  The data is updated very rarely so caching every hour would be fine.

Comment: In that case caching sounds like the way to go!